# How to easily clean up photo folder using Finder?

Tags: finder, photos

I am using OSX already for a couple of years, but I still have trouble finding a good workflow for cleaning up photos in a folder using Finder. What I like to do is view each of the photos and delete some of them. 
What I currently do is:

(a) put the relevant folder in List view (so I see all the details like size, and date modified), and 
(b) use quick look (by pressing spacebar) to see the photo. 
(c) Then I press cmd-backspace the delete the file if required.

The issue is: if I delete the file, the next file (or the preceding) file is not selected in Finder, which requires me to either use my mouse to select the next file (if I remember correctly which one it is), or (preferably) press the arrow keys a number of times to navigate to the relevant file.

In Windows Preview, deleting a file automatically shows the next file, which is very convenient.

What would be a good workflow to do this simple task in Finder?

(I don't want to use iPhoto etc. Using the icon view in Finder is not convenient either because the photos are too small and I can't use a single arrow key to go through each of the photos. I tried using Cover Flow in Finder, but I find the size of the photos also to be rather small)

Answer (score 1):

When I try this it works. Not that I would actually do this.

I use [QuollEyeTree](http://binnie.id.au/QuollEyeTree.html%20QuollEyeTree) (freeware)

This lets you `Tag` files of interest, then you can perform operations on the tagged files e.g. Delete, Move etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "When I try *this* it works"?

Answer (score 0):

I used to use [ViewIt](http://www.hexcat.com/viewit/) about £15 for the full version, but there is a freeware lite version.

You can go through folders of photos in full windowed or thumbnail view. Drag & drop a folder to the window to get started
Delete is by key command as I recall, Cmd/backspace same as the Finder. Next pic is selected in thumbnail view or brought to the current view in full window view.

Haven't needed it in years, so don't know how it's kept pace, but it might be worth checking out the lite version & also compare what you'd gain with the paid version.

*Edit - shows how long since I used it, sorry. The lite version is PPC only. The paid version will apparently run in permanent trial mode with nags.*

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, however I would like to refrain from using 3rd party software